# How can I embed a Visio 2007 editing control in my C# (.Net 3.5) application?

Tags: c#, .net, visio

I would like to embed a Visio editing interface in my C# form. The best instructions I have found so far are from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164043.aspx but they are outdated. The biggest problem I am having is trying to determine which control I actually need to add to my toolbox so I can drag and drop it to my form. Does anyone know how I can embed Visio? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I just found the answer:

Under `COM Components`, check `Microsoft Office Visio 12.0 Drawing Control`.